# OnCollisionEnter somehow not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make it so that when a player comes in contact with a ball called "ballInAir" it decreases the lives-count in the top right corner of the screen. It is not working. Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class livesScript : MonoBehaviour {
public Text livesText;
public float lives;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    livesText = GameObject.FindWithTag("lives").GetComponent<Text>();
    lives = 4;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    livesText.text = "Lives: " + lives;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision bol)
{
    if (bol.gameObject.name == "ballInAir")
    {

        lives = lives - 1;

    }

}

}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of game]

Rigidbody of the Ball:
[image: Rigidbody of the Ball]

Rigidbody of the player:
[image: Rigidbody of player]

Structure of the Player Prefab: [image]

The Capsule part of the prefab, the part attached to the script and the part that I want to detect collisions with the ball: [image]

[image]

The Firstpersoncontroller part of the prefab: [image]

Comment: Two kinematic rigidbody collision will not call the callback message.  Use Trigger for that. `
The `OnTriggerEnter(Collider)` function should do it.

Comment: @Programmer I'm making a dodgeball game and I want to make sure the ball is able to bounce and deflect off objects, would OnTriggerEnter still allow me to do that?

Comment: Not sure. Why can't use disable isKinematic on the ball then still use `OnCollisionEnter`. Is there a porblem with disabling isKinematic on the ball?

Comment: @Programmer I just experimented with making both Rigidbodies non-kinematic and it's still not counting lives. It might be a problem with the way my player is set up. I'm going to include a screenshot of my player Prefab in the question.

Comment: @Programmer It's a bit complex, but I've just posted images of the significant parts of my player prefab in the question.

Comment: Put Debug.Log in `OnCollisionEnter` and see if that's being called in the first place. Also, please label each object and what is colliding with what. Right now, I don't even know what's colliding with what

Comment: @Programmer I'm sorry, but something happened with my program and I most likely have to redo a lot of it. I'll get back to you.